# MySQL SELECT with varying WHERE fields

Tags: mysql, where-clause, varying

At a high-level this sounds trivial, but it turns out I've been scratching my head for a a couple of hours.

**Situation:**

I have table `T`, with columns `a,b,c,d,e`. Column `a` holds a string, while `b,c,d,e` each hold a boolean value.

I am allowing a user to perform a kind of *search*, where I prompt the user to enter values for `a,b,c,d,e`, and return all the rows where those values all match.

**In a perfect world**, the user enters all values (lets say `a="JavaScript"` , `b="true"`, `c="false"`, `d="false"`, `e="true"`) and a resulting query (In Scala, referencing a remote DB running MySQL) might look something like this:

```
connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM T 
WHERE a = '" + a_input + "' 
and b = " + b_input + "
and c = " + c_input + "
and d = " + d_input + "
and e = " + e_input + ";")
```

**Problem:**

I give the user the option to 'loosen' the constraints, so it is possible that **a_input=""** and **b_input=""**, etc... Potentially all fields **a,b,c,d,e** can be empty (**""**) If a field is omitted, it should not affect the resulting response. In other words, if `c` is not entered, the result can contain entries where `c` is **TRUE** or **FALSE**

**Question:**

How do I write **ONE** query that covers the situation where potentially all fields can be empty, or just some, or none?

Comment: like this: `where (b_input = '' or b = b_input) and (...)`

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
Select *
from table 
where  a in ('','othervalue','othervalue')
and b in ('','othervalue','morevalues')
```

and so on.....that is like using an or for each field and it will match even if it's empty

Comment: Thank you. If field1 is "", will it look for instances where field1 ="", or will it ignore field1 completely? If the former, this is not the functionality I need. I updated the Problem section in the OP to detail further what I need.

Comment: It will match anyway, cause you need to fullfill ANY of those values for each field, is like using an OR ..... '' or othervalue' or 'morevalues', just try it and you will see it works

Comment: Perhaps I was misunderstood, but I will try this query and let you know if it works, thank you.

Comment: nono, you were very clear. You want all the registries that may or may not contain any of the values and at the same time matches the values that the user filled. The IN clause is used in those situations where you have optional fields......

Comment: It isn't working. If I supply an argument, it works like expected, but if it is left empty, it is not letting all of them go through.

Comment: could you post the query in a pastebin a post the link?.....You must be doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just build the `WHERE` dynamically. Instead of always searching for `c = 'whatever'`, only include `c` in the `WHERE` if the user supplied a value for it.

Comment: How to do this in one query is the question without a ton of if() checking whether or not a value was supplied?

Comment: The only other option is to use juergen d's answer in the main comment section above. I have no idea what Juan is trying to say

Comment: Juerguen's answer is the same as mine, the only difference is that I'm using the IN clause but the meaning is exactly the same...

Comment: @Juan No. Yours says to pull records where `a` is blank or something else. His is saying pull records where `a_input` is blank or `a = a_input`.

Comment: it's the same as saying where a IN ('','a_input')  that will match any of the values.....I think this was just a missunderstanding but we wanted to say the same

Comment: With yours when the user doesn't supply a value for a_input the query will look like `WHERE a IN ('', '')`. The other suggestion (`WHERE (a = '$a_input' or '$a_input' = '')`) will make the query look like `WHERE (a = '' or '' = '')`

Comment: @RodmanGrenich, I think you should reconsider using a "ton" of `if`'s. It would reduce the amount of work the query has to do. If you build all the logic into the query, it will have to check the value of column A on every record even when you don't care what A is.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because the DB contains booleans but the parms are strings. Are the parms always blank. 'true', or 'false'? If so try

```
(B_input=''
 Or (b_input=''true' and b)
   Or (b_input='false' and ((not b)))
```